# SITEMAP.XML contains non-canonical links

Tags: magento2, seo, sitemaps, canonical

XML Sitemap contains a lot of non-canonical URLs in Magento 2.0.2. It's not good practice from SEO perspective and and worth fixing.

Here is my config:

- Use Categories Path for Product URLs is set to "No"
- Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products is set to "Yes"

And few lines from my sitemap:

```
http://example.com/women/tops-women/tanks-women/erica-evercool-sports-bra.html  (category path, Non-Canonical)
http://example.com/nora-practice-tank.html (Canonical)
...
```

All sitemap links should be equal to canonical links.

Could someone please have a look at it.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing when I first generated my sitemap. I ended up making a short extension module and tweaking the sitemap query for products.

The class that needs to be extended:
    `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product`

The function that needs to be overridden:
    `public function getCollection($storeId)`

Change the parameter in the `joinLeft` of the query from:

```
'e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1'
```

To the following:

```
'e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1 AND url_rewrite.metadata is null'
```

This works for me. I'm obviously not doing a check for the canonical configuration setting and just scoping on the meta-data field in the query. This HAS NOT been thoroughly tested, so I make no promises that this won't exclude products for some reason.

I hope this helps. Maybe there will be an official patch for this later, but for now this is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rajeev's answer requires overwriting the entire getCollection function, which is 50+ lines of concrete, specific code that might change in an upgrade.

I think a plugin is more upgrade proof, though slightly less efficient in terms of performance.

plugin declaration:

```
<type name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product">
    <plugin name="Vendor_SitemapProductUrlFix" type="Vendor\SitemapUrlFix\Plugin\Product"/>
</type>
```

and plugin file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SitemapUrlFix\Plugin;

class Product
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
 */
protected $productStatus;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
 */
protected $productVisibility;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}

public function afterGetCollection(\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product $subject, $result, $storeId)
{

    // create product url array (key = productId, value = product url)
        $productUrls = [];
        $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                            ->setStore($storeId)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
                            ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ;


        foreach ($productCollection as $product){
            $productId = (string) $product->getId();
            $storeUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl();

            $fullProductUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
            $productUrlPath = str_replace($storeUrl,"", $fullProductUrl);

            $productUrls[$productId] = $productUrlPath;
        }

    // replace sitemap collection item's 'url' property with product's "product_url" attribute
        $collection = $result;
        foreach ($collection AS $item){
            $productId = (string) $item->getId();
            if ($replacementUrl = $productUrls[$productId]){
                $item->setUrl($replacementUrl);
            }
        }


    return $result;
}

}
```