# Magento2.4.3: How to stop adding non-canonical url from in sitemap.xml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have 400k products in my store and when I generate a sitemap it contains  **non-canonical** URL, is there any way I can stop adding **non-canonical** URLs in sitemap.xml,
and still be able to generate sitemap.
any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Please follow this link 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105114/sitemap-xml-contains-non-canonical-links